# Force LibreOffice 5.1.2.2 to use gtk2 instead of gtk3?

Tags: libreoffice, gtk3, gtk-2

I have `LibreOffice Version: 5.1.2.2, Build ID: 1:5.1.2-0ubuntu1` running on Lubuntu 16.04 LTS. It defaults to `gtk3`, but I want to know if I can switch it to `gtk2` instead as hinted by comment #7 in https://bugs.launchpad.net/df-libreoffice/+bug/1527053. Is that possible? `man libreoffice` makes no mention of such a possibility.

Comment: I could switch between gtk2 and gtk3 by removing libreoffice-gtk2 and installing libreoffice-gtk3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start libreoffice with the environment variable `SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN` set to `gtk`:

`SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gtk libreoffice`

Depending on how you set up environment variables at boot, you can include the setting in the appropriate places.

Works for me under Arch Linux.

Note: Also supported: `SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=kde4` for Qt, for example. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LibreOffice#Theme.

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall **libreoffice-gtk3** if you need the GTK2 version of LibreOffice.