# Dark Libreoffice theme from Gnome?

Tags: gnome, libreoffice, 16.10

I am using Ubuntu with gnome, and per the tweak tool I set the global theme to dark. Even though I have libreoffice-gtk installed, Calc and Writer seem to pay no attention as seen in the photo. Any recommendations? I specifically want the application area such as between the icons to be dark. I know this is possible because installing libreoffice-gtk into Deepin OS yielded exactly what I wanted but I can't seem to duplicate it in Ubuntu Gnome.[image]

Comment: I am currently running LibreOffice with a dark GTK theme, so I know it is possible. Perhaps your theme is only GTK3 and your LibreOffice is using GTK2 or vice versa? LibreOffice can use either. See https://askubuntu.com/q/765950